# Backup docker volume on a broken system. Volume recovery

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, coreos, docker-volume

I have a server that's been running in docker on coreos. For some reason containerd has stopped running and the docker daemon has stopped working correctly. My efforts to debug haven't gotten far. I'd like to just boot a new instance and migrate, but I'm not sure I can backup my volume without a working docker service. Is it possible to backup my volume without using docker?

Most search results assume a running docker system, and don't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, docker volumes are stored in /var/lib/docker/volumes.  Being that you don't have a working docker setup, you might have to dive into the subfolders to figure out which volume you're concerned with, but that should at least give you a start.  If it's helpful, in a working docker environment, you can inspect docker volumes outlined [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes), and get all necessary information you would need to carry this out.